# Having issues in writing a dictionary to a csv file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am writing the api_move_resp to a csv file using the pandas. It writes the data but only once for the last userid that it picks from a text file.

What changes i can do to write the data from api_move_resp as a new line for every iteration. Also how i can add the headings to the csv.  I am new to python.

```
while i < length:
    userid1 = content[i].strip()
    api_endpoint1 = "https://api.XXXXXXXX.com/v1/user/"+str(admin_userid)+"/meeting_history/move_recordings/from_user/"+str(userid1)+"/to_user/"+str(admin_userid)         
    param = {'access_token':access}
    api_move = requests.post(url= api_endpoint1, params = param)
    status = api_move.status_code
    api_move_resp = json.loads(api_move.text)   
    (pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=api_move_resp, orient='columns')
    .to_csv('dict_file.csv', header=False))       
    if status == 200:        
        print(api_move_resp['message'], "From", api_move_resp['fromUserInfo']['firstName'], api_move_resp['fromUserInfo']['lastName'], "To The Admin Account") 
    else:
      print(api_move.status_code)
    i += 1
```

Comment: where is your iteration ?

Comment: you are wrting to a file called dict_file. its not that onyl the last data is writen, its jst in every iteration the data is overwriten. Henc u can only see the the last iterations data. See how u can append to the file instead of overwriting. Add `mode=a` as one of the named params to `to_csv`.

Comment: @leoOrion I now added the mode='a' to append the lines and it is now writing all the data to the file but the first name and last name are now coming in two lines

Comment: without sample data it is difficult to realize what your intended output vs actual output is.

Comment: My json response is this, so now the firstName is showing in first line with all the other data but then the lastname is showing in next line with the same data again. so for three iterations, it is creating 6 lines instead of 3 {"id":114797,"from_user_id":4439983,"to_user_id":551806,"initiator_user_id":551806,"status":"SUCCESS","created":1627033239000,"fromUserInfo":{"firstName":"Sachin","lastName":"testing12"},"code":200,"message":"Successfully Moved Recordings"}

Comment: remove the `orient=columns`

Comment: looks like the nested dicts are printed as two lines

Comment: it wont. the entire dict will be printed as a string for that column